# Emails created in Marketing Cloud aren't fully responsive on the Outlook Mobile app for iOS

Tags: ios, email, outlook, responsive, salesforce-marketing-cloud

The responsive layout blocks in Marketing Cloud, Content Builder are made to stack content on mobile devices using `<td class="responsive-td">`. This changes table cells to display:block at small screen sizes and works fine in Apple Mail but not the Outlook Mobile app for iOS.

The Outlook app apparently strips the Doctype from emails so that table cells can't be changed to display:block on iOS. The only known workaround I found is to change the TD's to TH's, however this can't be done in Content Builder since the HTML in layout blocks is locked.

Is there some way to change TD's to TH's in Marketing Cloud layout blocks or is there a better solution to the Outlook Mobile app problem in iOS? Outlook on Android devices is not affected by this issue.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out by any chance ?

Comment: I have exactly the same question. It's been almost 3 years and Salesforce didn't bother to fix that issue. It was also flagged here - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/294880/marketing-cloud-responsive-layouts-not-responsive/369725